# csv string comparison not working

Tags: php, csv, encoding, utf-8, php-5.4

I'm checking if a string appears in an array filled with `fgetcsv()`, I've checked the content and the string it's contained at the array but `in_array()` returns `false`

```
function checkFieldCSV($index,$code){
    $codes  = array();
    if (($handle = fopen("./csv/file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            array_push($codes, explode(';', $data[0])[$index] );
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    $codes = removeCommas($codes);
    var_dump($codes);
    var_dump($code);
    return in_array($code, $codes);
}
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: @mickmackusa the dump is added

Comment: Can we see any of the raw .csv text?  I'd like to isolate what and where the invisible characters are.  `Eines IMI/Easyvista/Explotació de dades` has four invisible characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to search in a two dimensional array.

```
array_push($codes, explode(';', $data[0])[$index] );
```

this will result in $codes[0][0...n] so in array wont work.

try the following

```
$found = false;
foreach($codes as $key=>$value){
   $found = in_array($code, $value);
}
return $found;
```

Code is not tested, let me know if this has helped you.

Comment: is not  a two dimensional array ,I've tried comparing a single element and fails too

Comment: Do you have double checked the case sensitivity? in_array() is case sensitive

Comment: `[5]=> string(26) "Telefonia/IPAD/Consulta"`
and
`string(23) "Telefonia/IPAD/Consulta"` have different length. meight be an encoding problem? Give [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) a try.

Comment: If I use `mb_detect_encoding` I get the following error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()` in php 5.4.13

Comment: There meight be whitespaces or not printable chars in the string. may be your csv is broken?